# Transiting through the U.S with b1/b2 after filing a DS160 for a different type of Visa

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, working-visas

I have an approved I-129 petition for nonimmigrant worker, I filed the ds-160 form and need to attend an interview in the U.S Consulate in Mexico to get my working visa.
I am currently in Italy, can I fly from here into the u.s, then cross the border immediately to Mexico to attend my consulate interview using my b1/b2? Will that affect my interview? I already filed the DS160 and entered the estimated dates of my last entries in to the U.S, so, can I enter and exit the u.s one more time before the interview?